# Action after XSS successfully

Tags: xss

Let say my site is vulnerable by xss.
What happend then.

Javascript nowaday cannot get the cookie (HttpOnly is marked 'true')

Could the attacker do something specific on my site then?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying that your website is vulnerable to XSS and it enabled HttpOnly flag.

If the victim's browser supports HttpOnly flag then the attacker can't get cookie of victim as it is not accessible by malicious script but what if the victim's browser does not support HttpOnly flag? In this case, the browser ignores the HttpOnly flag and creates normal accessible cookie, so the attacker can get cookie.

HttpOnly flag does not prevent execution of malicious script, so the attacker can do much more things. 
Ex. Key logger, redirecting user to malicious sites, injecting fake login forms, etc.

Comment: All major browsers support the HttpOnly flag, so I would say the last part is the crux of this.

Comment: @Erlend Yeah. I agree